# table with columns data from different table

Tags: sql, hive

I want to create table with two columns and inserting data into columns from 
two different tables. I'm using query which generates cross product of source table.

Query below :-

```
create table test 
as 
select a.offer_id as offer_id,b.poid as poid 
from (select distinct offer_id from table1 limit 5) a, (select distinct poid from table2 limit 5) b;
```

how to avoid cross product.

Comment: I expect total no of rows as 5 , but it is coming as 25.

Comment: This is because the corss product of your tables is in fact each possible combination of two rows, one from each table. You might want to connect certain rows together based on common values. In that case you should use JOIN instead.

Comment: Can you please share the table structure.

Comment: both source tables have lots of columns. I just want to merge unique columns from source table in destination table as col1,col2

Comment: If there is any similar column present in both the source table then you can join both the tables with that column.

Comment: there is no similar column in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want something like this:

```
select a.offer_id as offer_id, b.poid as poid 
from (select offer_id, row_number() over (order by rand()) as seqnum
      from (select distinct offer_id from table1 limit 5) a
     ) a join
     (select poid, row_number() over (order by rand()) as seqnum
      from (select distinct poid from table2 limit 5) b
     ) b
     on a.seqnum = b.seqnum;
```